# Non-real root for a recursive difference equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion

I was helped by user12339314 who helped me to solve a recursive difference equation in MATLAB. I have tried to apply the method to a slightly more complicated recursive equation, and it works too. This time, I have x(t+1) on the left-hand-side, and on the right-hand-side I have x(t) and x(t-1), i.e., the difference equation of order 3. And the method works, but I am little puzzled why I am getting a complex number, whose real part is the solution. I know the dynamics of xt are oscillatory, and it converges to 0.0480162880552655, but after I run the code below, and click on x, I see it converges to 0.0480162880552655 + 1.55851090378119e-67i. I am not sure why this happens. I tried different initial guesses, but the problem does not go away. Below is the code. Thank you for your help.

```
tic

clear
clc
format long;

time = 0:1:100;

A = 1.00;
h = 0.90;
beta  = 0.40;
alpha = 0.36;
n = 0.10;
xstar = 0.3581201041248495;
kstartheir = (alpha*A*xstar/h)^(1/(1-alpha));

zeta1 = 1/(1+beta+beta^2);
a = (1-zeta1+zeta1*beta^2*h/(1+n))/(zeta1+(1+h+n)*alpha/(h*(1-alpha)));
b = (zeta1*beta^2*h/(1+n))/(zeta1+(1+h+n)*alpha/(h*(1-alpha)));

recEq = @(p,q,z) ((1-alpha)*A*p^alpha/(1+h+n))*(1-zeta1*(1+h*q/(A*alpha*p^alpha))+(zeta1*beta^2*h/(1+n))*((1+h*p/(A*alpha*z^alpha))/(h*p/(A*alpha*z^alpha))));
x = nan(1, 100);
x(1) = 12200;
for t = 1:100
    kold = x(t);
    k = recEq(x(t),kold,kold);
    while abs(k-kold) > 1e-8
        kold = k;
        k = recEq(x(t), kold,kold);
    end
    x(t+1) = k;
end

toc
```

Comment: The imaginary part is 1.55851090378119e-67. this may be a numerical zero, a roundoff error. Are you sure the correct result is 0.0480162880552655?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong, what is `p`, `q` and `z` (who is `x(t)`, `x(t+1)` and `x(t-1)`), but you wrote `k = recEq(x(t),kold,kold)`. 

You should have `kold = x(t)` and `kold2=x(t-1)` and call it `k = recEq(x(t),kold,kold2)` (or the correct ordering for how you defined `p`, `q` and `z`)

Comment: hi. how would the code be modified then? should I guess x(t-1) too? I am a little confused.

Comment: Yes, you should. If you have a second order difference equation, you probably have x(1) and x(2), the initial conditions. The `while` loop is a (very simple) method to find the root of equation (namely, to get the `x(t+1)`). So you should provise both values to your equation. I can help a little more if you tell me what your difference equation or, equivalently, if `p=x(t+1)`, `q=x(t)` and `z=x(t-1)` or so, how you defined your variables?.

Comment: Hi thanks! My difference equation is of the following form (parameters are specified in the loop above): 
y(t+1)=((1-alpha)*A*y(t)^alpha/(1+h+n))*(1-zeta1*(1+h*y(t+1)/(A*alpha*y(t)^alpha))+(zeta1*beta^2*h/(1+n))*((1+h*y(t)/(A*alpha*y(t-1)^alpha))/(h*y(t)/(A*alpha*y(t-1)^alpha))))
I do not have any initial conditions, basically the dynamics of yt should be oscillaroty and yt should converge to 0.0480.

Comment: No initial conditions? How did you find this value `x(1) = 12200;` ?

Comment: Just a guess. it will converge. set x(1) to any other value, it should converge in this particular case.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to make it work, without a complex number appearing. Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, what you got, is a nonlinear recurrence equation.
In order to get the `x(t+1)`, you must solve (numerically) the recurrence equation to obtain it.

The idea user12339314 gave was a simple recurrence to find the [fixed point of your equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration). It is a simple root-finding algorithm.

Because now your recurrence equation has 3 terms, namely, `x(t+1)`, `x(t)` and `x(t-1)`, you must use these 3 values to find the root `x(t+1)`. Changing a little your code, in order to make it clearer the "rood-finding part" of your code, we can write:

```
tic;clear;clc;format long;

time = 0:1:100;

A = 1.00;
h = 0.90;
beta  = 0.40;
alpha = 0.36;
n = 0.10;
xstar = 0.3581201041248495;
kstartheir = (alpha*A*xstar/h)^(1/(1-alpha));

zeta1 = 1/(1+beta+beta^2);
a = (1-zeta1+zeta1*beta^2*h/(1+n))/(zeta1+(1+h+n)*alpha/(h*(1-alpha)));
b = (zeta1*beta^2*h/(1+n))/(zeta1+(1+h+n)*alpha/(h*(1-alpha)));

recEq = @(p,q,z) ((1-alpha)*A*p^alpha/(1+h+n))*(1-zeta1*(1+h*q/(A*alpha*p^alpha))+(zeta1*beta^2*h/(1+n))*((1+h*p/(A*alpha*z^alpha))/(h*p/(A*alpha*z^alpha))));
x = nan(1, 100);
x(1) = 12200;
x(2) = 12200; % notice we must provide now 2 guesses, because we need 2 initial conditions

for t = 2:100
    k = x(t);
    kold = x(t);
    kold2 = x(t-1);

    % root finding algorithm to obtain x(t+1)
    converged = false;
    while ~converged
        kk = k;
        k = recEq(kold, kk, kold2);

        if(abs(k-kk)<1e-8)
            converged = true;
        end
    end
    x(t+1) = k;
end

toc
```

Notice a few things:

- we must provide 2 initial conditions. So we define `x(1) = 12200;` and `x(2) = 12200;`
- Given the equation you provided, you named in your recursive equation `recEq` the three variables: `p=x(t)`, `q=x(t+1)` and `z=x(t-1)`. Since you are looking for the root `x(t+1)`, this is the variable `k` that you must define as the unknown. `p` and `z` are known (from the previous iterations or from the initial conditions in the first iteration).

Running this code, no round-off errors are introduced. The complex numbers are likely to appear in the exponentiation, with the wrong assignment (in your code) `p,q,z` in `k = recEq(x(t), kold,kold);`. Notice the difference from my code.

A last comment is that in the equation, you can use any root-finding algorithm. This is very interesting because, knowing that, you can use any built-in function to find the root. The advantage is that MATLAB's built-in functions are much better than any simple code you may write. We can change the loop to write it like:

```
for t = 2:100
    fun = @(k) recEq(x(t),k,x(t-1))-k;
    x(t+1) = fzero(fun,x(t));
    % x(t+1) = fsolve(fun,x(t));
end
```

To use the [fzero](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) or the [fsolve](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) built-in functions. You will get the same results (and for this particular case, `fzero` will run much faster than `fsolve`).
If you have any other equation (even more difficult to solve), just use the built-in function and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question about the convergence tolerance. Right now, it is set to <1e-8. Does it mean that it will keep on computing until the difference between x and previous x are small enough? The reason I am confused is because if <1e-8 is changed to something bigger, like 0.10, then it still keeps on computing till the last value of time, even though subsequent x values are very very close to one another. Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: There are two things happening: the 1e-8 is the tolerance you just said - this is the while loop. The other thing is the calculation for each time step - the for loop. So you look for the root in each for-loop.